# SQL Server 2008, convert float to string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to convert float field (sp.[Current]) to string. The part of the query is:

```
SELECT 
    cast(sp.CustID as varchar(10)) CustID,
    cast(sp.Year as varchar(4)) Year,
    convert(nvarchar(50), sp.[Current])  AS Potential,
    sp.[Current] as Potential1
```

But after converting I get this result

[image]

I get exponential notation of the number. How can I improve it?

Comment: DId you check the documentation for `CONVERT`?

Comment: What you have does that. What's the problem?

Comment: The [section on float and real styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#float-and-real-styles) in `CONVERT`'s docs explain how you can control the output. It's far better to let the *client* control formatting though. SQL, the language isn't all that great for formatting. In *supported* SQL Server versions, you could use the [FORMAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function but again, *clients* are far better at formatting

Comment: Why are using `float` as well? There are use cases for it, but `float` (and `real`) are imprecise data types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to this link [How to use STR SQL SERVER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/str-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15)  as illustrated below

```
SELECT STR(float,25, 2)
```

Good Luck .

Comment: if it work, you need to tick as the right solution .

Answer (score 0):

you can try like below

```
CONVERT(numeric(16,0), CAST([Current] AS FLOAT))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DECLARE @val float = 2000000.890

select convert(nvarchar(50),CAST(@val AS numeric(16,4)))
```